# Can OpenOffice Calc AutoInput reference data on a different sheet?

Tags: openoffice, openoffice-calc

I've set up a spreadsheet in OpenOffice for project estimation at a contractor. The first column is a description of the item or service that I'm adding into the price. Since there are many commonly used items that pop up again and again, I've added a sheet onto the end of the workbook with a list of some of them and a drop down list to the first column of the first page that references that list on the final sheet. I would like, if possible, to be able to simply start typing into the box on the first page and have it autocomplete with items from that list. Is this possible?

[First Picture is the spreadsheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/17tlA.png)
[The setup for the drop-down](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b65zl.png)

Comment: Are you using OpenOffice or LibreOffice? I know you have indicated OpenOffice, I just want to be 100% sure.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio OpenOffice